# McCormick envelopes

Tags: convex-analysis, upper-lower-bounds, convex-hulls

McCormick envelopes  [(Definition here)](https://optimization.mccormick.northwestern.edu/index.php/McCormick_envelopes) are used to bound the bilinear (non-convex) functions. Is it possible to bound a bilinear term with non-integral bounds? I have this doubt because, in almost all the research papers, only Mixed Integer Linear Programming (MILP) is referred, and there is no mention or example where non-integral bounds are used. I am asking this question because I am trying to bound a bilinear term but it has non-integer bound (in my case $(1,2)$).

Comment: These envelopes work as well with non-integer bounds on the variables.

Comment: @daw Thank you for answering.